# AFHTTPRequestOperation times out

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsoperation

I have a few web services calls in my app. Here is an example of how I'm calling them

```
+(void) login:(NSDictionary *) loginParams {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate  = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSString * URLString = [MPTLogin getLoginWSAddress];
    AFHTTPClient* client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                    path:URLString
                                              parameters:loginParams];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"didSuccessfullyAttemptLogin" object:nil userInfo:nil];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if ([operation.response statusCode] == 401)
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"invalidUserNameOrPassword" object:self userInfo:nil];

        else
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"didFailedAttemptLogin" object:self userInfo:nil];
    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

The issue is, if no web service is called in 5-15 minutes, the next web service called times out. Then any calls after that take only an instance of a second to complete, untill there is no calls are made for a few minutes. Then the same things happens again.

This only happens on device. Simulator is fine. Also, this is not a wifi issue. I am totally lost as to how I can debug this.

**Update**: So I checked the server logs and the calls do not arrive on time.
I also tried using [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/). The most bizarre thing happened. When the proxy is on, the time out does not happen. In fact, the calls almost happen instantly. But when I take off the proxy, the same issue happens.

**Update:** This is not a wifi issue because we have tried it on different devices, different wifi connections, in different states.

**Update** So I ended up setting the timeouts to 150 seconds. Now, I have fewer timeouts but the problem is that whenever I get a timeout, the console says it took 60ish seconds. Also the timeout code is -1001

Comment: What are the example values for loginParams and URLString? It is working with proxy but not working without proxy? Could the server thinks the request as spam request? Just a random guess.

Comment: loginParams is the dictionary:     @{@"userName": @"simpleString", @"password": @"smipleString", @"deviceName": @"Somestring_anInt"};

Comment: The timeouts that you set is on the server side or timeoutInterval on NSMutableURLRequest? If it is for NSMutableURLRequest, the 150 seconds is way too long. Can you screen shot or paste the time out error log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience working with web services and also AFHTTPRequest, the **request timed out** is mostly server/network related. If you are confirmed that the server does not have any problem, I think the best you can do is giving the request to a **timeoutInterval** (eg: 15 seconds). Next, if you still receive the request timed out error, you can make a try the same operation for **N times**.

For example, you can do something like:-

**Calling the function with 3 retries:**

```
[ServerRequest yourMethodName:yourLoginDict with:3];
```

**The Function:-**

```
+(void)yourMethodName:(NSDictionary *) loginParams with:(NSUInteger)ntimes {

if (ntimes <= 0) {
    NSLog(@"Request failed after trying for N times");
}
else{

    NSDictionary * postDictionary = loginParams;
    NSError * error = nil;
    NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"YOUR URL"];

    //Give the Request 15 seconds to load
    NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:15.0];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:jsonData];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:urlRequest];
    [operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Successful request");
    }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Request Failed at %d: %@",ntimes,error);

        //If the request failed, call again with ntimes-1
        [self yourMethodName:loginParams with:ntimes-1];
        }
     ];
    [operation start];
 }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am going to try this. So this issue is causing 2 things. The first is just a very long wait and the second a failure. This will avoid the failure but I am still looking to avoid the wait.

Comment: No problem. If the waiting time is too long, you can reduce the timeoutInterval to may be 10 or 5 seconds. It really depends on what you need. If you face this issue consistently, I think the problem is really on the connection or your server side. Not really the problem on your frontend code.

Comment: May be you can report back any performance or issue after trying the code on your end, I will see what I can help further.

Answer (score 1):

//Create Twitter Account
-(void)createTwitterAccountWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary
                      WithCompletionBlock:(void(^)(user *userObj,NSString *errorMessager))completionBlock{

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] initWithBaseURL:BASE_URL];
[SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];

[manager POST:KCreateTwitterAccount parameters:dictionary success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Request url:%@",operation.request.URL);
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
    if ([responseObject[@"status"]isEqualToString:@"SUCCESS"]) {
        user *userObj = [[user alloc]initWithUserDictionary:responseObject[@"data"]];
        completionBlock(userObj,nil);
        [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Success"];
    }
    else{
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        completionBlock(nil,responseObject[@"message"]);
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Request url:%@",operation.request.URL);
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Failure"];
}];
```

}

and in AFURLResponseSerialization.m 
did these changes

```
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }
#pragma mark - did changes
    //add this @"text/html"
    self.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil];

    return self;
}
```